# findByIdAndUpdate $set does not check for unique?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have a schema and specify login is unique is true. When I use findByIdAndUpdate and pass query $set to update an user object, it did **not** throw back error when login is dup. Does anyone know why and how I should update an object and force schema validation?

Thanks!

```
// UserSchema.js
var schema = new Schema({
  login: {
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    index: true,
    type: String
  }
});


// Update
UserSchema.findByIdAndUpdate('someID', { '$set': { login: 'abc' } }, function (error, user) {
    callback(error, user);
});
```

Comment: Nam, Are u using client side validation through JavaScript to check for duplicate login attempt?
This requires interaction with the server. Isn't it? Moreover your question needs an edit for others to understand it clearly.

Comment: @Rajesh Paul, my question is related to Node.js and Mongoose.js, it is not about client side though.

Comment: Ok, then its not my area.

Comment: no problem @ Rajesh Paul, thanks!

Comment: You need to give `login` a `type` value in your schema.  Maybe that's just a typo as Mongoose should be throwing an exception if you leave it out.

Comment: @JohnnyHK, I accidentally took it out when I trim down sample versions, but I had it while doing it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the shorthand helper methods in Mongoose bypasses validation, so you need to use a 3 step approach:

1. Find
2. Edit
3. Save

For example:

```
// 1: Find
UserSchema.findById( 'someID',
  function (err, user) {
    if(!err){
      // 2: Edit
      user.login = 'abc';
      // 3: Save
      user.save(function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return;
        }
        console.log('User saved: ' + user);
      });
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: This isn't correct as `unique` index constraints are enforced within MongoDB so Mongoose's own validation isn't involved.

Comment: @Simon Holmes, it works as expected. I found out that that if I'm using findByIdAndUpdate and call $set or $unset commands, the schema validation will not apply.

Answer (score 5):

You simply need to set runValidators to true:

```
findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {$set: data}, {runValidators: true}, function (err, doc) {
    if (err) {
        // Handle validation errors
    }
})
```

More here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findOneAndUpdate

Comment: This is a much better answer than the accepted. Using the `$set` update operation, in the case of the OP's scenario, is preferred since the only update to the document that should take place is on the "login" field. The purposes of `$set`, `$push`, `$pull`, and others, is to ensure we don't have conflicting updates occurring at the same time.